# HTML 5 Canvas - Get pixel data for a path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wonder if is there any way I can get pixel data for the currently drawn path in the canvas tag.

I can calculate the pixel data on my own when drawing simple shapes like square or a line, but  things get messy with more complicated shapes like ellipse or even a simple circle.

The reason i'm asking this is because I'm working on a web application which involves sending canvas pixels data to the server when I add a path to the canvas. The server needs to keep it's own copy of the entire canvas, and I really don't want to send the ENTIRE canvas image every single change, but only the delta for efficiency reasons...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Draw the paths to a second canvas of the same size as you original, let's call it the 'path canvas'.

Step 2: Set the globalCompositeOperation of the path canvas to 'destination-in'.

Step 3: draw you original canvas onto the path canvas

Step 4: Loop through all the pixels of the path canvas and store the pixels that are not transparent in whatever format you're sending them to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this will obviously do what is needed but it's not very efficient to follow these steps every time I add something to the canvas...

Comment: What about instead of copying the entire original canvas, I will track the. smallest bounding rectangle of the path, use getImageData only on this section and then putImageData on the paths canvas and then collect only the non transparent pixels?

Comment: That would be faster depending on the size of each drawing operation, but what is this for? Are you sure it's not better to just keep a record of each drawing operation and repeat them as needed? Pixel data is generally not the most efficient way of storing things.

Comment: It's for a drawing board collaboration tool for college, I'm trying to  find what's the best way for the server to keep track of the most latest drawing. so each time a user joins the 'room', the server can send him the latest drawing. As part of this, when a user draws something on the drawing board, he needs to notify the server somehow, and the server sends it on to the other users in the 'room', so far no problem, but when a new guy gets in the 'room', the server needs to send him the latest drawing.

Comment: Continuing my last comment: I can obviously keep all drawing operations as JSON or as any other format, and send ALL operations to the joining user, but that contains a terrible efficiency problem, the server needs to save a stack which grows more and more each time. Not to mention that it will take a while for the client who just entered the 'room' some time to iterate over the entire set of operations and apply it, depending on the number of operations, this may take a while... you can see the problem...

Comment: definitely saving a stack of drawing operations for people currently in the room is going to be better than pixel data. For users just entering the room use the toDataURL method to grab a png of the current canvas. Since that'll be compressed it'll be way more efficient than pixel data.

Comment: But how does toDataURL helps me? It's a client side feature, not a server one... I can't quite follow what you're suggesting..

Comment: the same way getting pixel data helps. So presumably you've got all your users polling a server that tracking what all the users are doing to their canvases. When a user does something you post that to the server, when all the other users have registered that action it gets deleted. When a new user joins, you register that with whatever existing user polls the server next, and grab a dataURL of his canvas, then post that back to the server, where the new user will grab it (with any new changes from other users). Draw the dataURL to his canvas, then apply whatever changes.

Comment: Fair enough, but that basically requires me to get that data from existing users, but yet I still want to keep an up to date image so when everyone leaves the room, the server will still hold the room data. Besides, counting on other clients to bring this info smells a bit wrong to me

Comment: Use toDataURL to grab copy of the canvas from the last user to leave, and store it on the server as an image file. If you want to preserve undo functionality as well, you'd have to store a stack of user actions on the server as well. Then you can restore the session whenever.

Comment: @hobberwickey, Saving the stack doesn't scale. Sending the pixels is O(1). Saving the stack is O(n). where n can be infinite. When n exceeds a huge number of operations, **you would have to send the pixels anyway**.

Comment: If you wanted to preserve undo functionality, I don't see any other way. Of course you could always just limited the stack count for any given drawing session. Storing undo to begin with seems crazy to begin with to me anyway.